# How to capture the system inactivity while using single-spa also How to capture the error code in single spa

Tags: reactjs, timeout, single-spa

We are using single-spa in our react app to load our micro frontends. We want to redirect the users after 15minutes of inactivity. Can you please confirm if there is any built-in method to do that?

Also please help me with the error code capturing in the `addErrorHandler` method. Basically I want to read the error code when there is a API call failure.

Comment: No, `single-spa` is not concerned about inactivity.  Implement your own inactivity-tracking algorithm, and when the algorithm says it is time to redirect the user, redirect the user.

Comment: Which error code do you refer to?  Are you using [addErrorHandler](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/api/#adderrorhandler)?